# simplecaptcha-1.2.1.jar cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, zip

POM.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nl.captcha/simplecaptcha -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>nl.captcha</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplecaptcha</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Java build path Problems

Description:    Resource    Path    Location    Type Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/RAJAT/.m2/repository/nl/captcha/simplecaptcha/1.2.1/simplecaptcha-1.2.1.jar' in project 'wheelmonk' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file  wheelmonk       Build path  Build Path Problem

Answer (score 1):

The referenced jar is a valid jar on maven central repo, so this can be excluded as a reason. Please first check your jar file if it has actually been download correctly and can be opened by e.g. 7zip.

If anything is broken on this jar file delete it and re-resolve it.

Comment: yes you are right, the downloaded jar is broken, then i deleted it and re-downloaded it, facing same issue after that is downloaded it as jar form repo url and it's also broken,
conclusion -> the jar at central repo needs to be repackaged

Comment: also reported to them

Comment: i cannot confirm this, for me the jar on central is totally fine.

Comment: yup, maybe check if you have a proxy if it is configured properly. Laos you can try opening the downloaded "jar" in a text editor, maybe it will say something like an http error etc.

Answer (score 1):

If u already download or having the captcha.jar in the project folder or anywhere in your local storage,

```
 mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=nl.captcha -DartifactId=simplecaptcha -Dversion=1.2.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=**your-path-to-jar***
```

Add to this command and run the IDE terminal or project path CMD to initializing the .jar file and came up with build success, Then u can build the project successfully.